Css modules doesn't work with rollup and postcss
I have setup a component library using rollup and typescript and I'm trying to enable css modules inside postcss but it is throwing error
Note: I'm using it inside storybook
I'm using rollup-plugin-postcss and it's official docs says that we just need to pass modules: true, to enable css modules but it doesn't seem to be working
Inside my component
import s from "./Badge.css"

<div
      className={cn(s.badgeContainer, classes?.root)}
>
.......
</div>

Error

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      postcss({
        plugins: [],
        modules: true,
      }),
      typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
      terser(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
    ],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  },
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/types.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
    plugins: [
      dts.default(),
      postcss({
        sourceMap: true,
        modules: true,
        extract: false, 
        plugins: [],
        writeDefinitions: true,
        config: {
          path: "./postcss.config.js"
        },
    }),
    ],
    external: [/\.css$/],
  },
];

